# How to display selected month from Calendar into text box in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, datepicker, calendar

I wanted to ask how can I display selected month from calendar and display into my text box? I tried to use ToString(), but it still didn't work. I'm thinking there's difference in date picker and calendar, still not sure. Can anyone please help me out here? Thanks alot. Here's my coding;

In xaml;

```
 Calendar Name ="dteSelectedMonth" DisplayMode="Year" SelectionMode="SingleDate" DisplayModeChanged="dteSelectedMonth_DisplayModeChanged" DisplayDateChanged="monthCalendar_DataChanged"
```

In xaml.cs;

```
private void monthCalendar_DataChanged(object sender, CalendarDateChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        monthDisplay.Text = dteSelectedMonth.SelectedDate.ToString();
    }
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: The exception indicates that your selected date is not yet set. use: `monthDisplay.Text = dteSelectedMonth?.SelectedDate?.ToString();` and once the whole date has been selected, the selected date will be shown

Comment: `monthDisplay.Text = dteSelectedMonth?.SelectedDate?.ToString("MM");` will show selected month as two digits `monthDisplay.Text = dteSelectedMonth?.SelectedDate?.ToString("MMM");` will show month as text

Comment: for more formats see here: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/date-and-time-format-in-c-sharp-programming1

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Nawed, it still returns the same error after I tried it.

Comment: I see now that you are setting the event for `DisplayDateChanged`, use `SelectedDateChanged` instead. otherwise your `SelectedDate` is never set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get the selected month using the `DisplayDate` property. Make sure that the `IsLoaded` property returns true before you try to set the `Text` property:

```
private void monthCalendar_DataChanged(object sender, CalendarDateChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (IsLoaded && dteSelectedMonth.DisplayDate != null)
        monthDisplay.Text = dteSelectedMonth.DisplayDate.ToString("MMM");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `CalendarDateChangedEventArgs` object and its property `AddedDate`. When the event is fired, it will contain the previously selected day in the new month. Then you can convert it to any string format, e.g. to get the month.

Comment: I'm sorry, still couldn't get it, can you show me an example how to use AddedDate property? Thank you.

Comment: @JohnDing in your case it will be something like this in ```monthCalendar_DataChanged``` method: ```monthDisplay.Text = e.AddedDate?.ToString();```

Answer (score 0):

Please check your monthDisplay textbox is null or not. This happens because the displayDteChanged event fires before the initialization of the textbox (If you have the declaration of TextBox before that of Calendar). Add a null check to handle this.

```
if (monthDisplay != null)
            monthDisplay.Text = e.AddedDate?.Month.ToString();
```